# Convert Numpy array to ctypes `int` pointer to call Cython function from Python

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I am attempting the vendor the method `_select_by_peak_distance` from `scipy.signal._peak_finding_utils`. This is a cython `.pyx` file and the function has the signature:

```
def _select_by_peak_distance(np.intp_t[::1] peaks not None,
                             np.float64_t[::1] priority not None,
                             np.float64_t distance):
```

I have -recompiled `_peak_finding_utils.pyx` locally with a setup.py file below.

I have imported the function into Python and am now trying to call it. Naively I have started with
calling with `np.array[int], np.array[float],  float` however I got an error related to the first argument:

```
*** ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'intp_t' but got 'long'
```

I see the first argument should be a pointer to an integer array, not integers. So I tried to cast the numpy array to a pointer based on the numpy `ctypes` documentation:

```
pointer = my_array.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
```

However, calling the function with this argument results in the error:

```
*** ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 0)
```

I have researched this but cannot find the underlying cause and feel like the `int` casting procedure is wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize(
        "_peak_finding_utils.pyx", compiler_directives={"language_level": "3"},  # TODO: what does this do.
    ),
    include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to call it with `peaks.astype(np.intp)` and similarly with `np.float64` for your priority array e.g.:

```py
# dummy data
peaks = np.array([1, 2, 3])
priority = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
distance = 0.5

select_by_peak_distance(peaks.astype(np.intp), priority.astype(np.float64), distance)
```

Note that this will fail if you have values over 2^63-1 in your peeks array on 64-bit platforms (and over 2^31-1 on 32-bit platforms)